# System restart using python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, restart

I've a python code which measures performance of system for 3 retries after each retry the system has to restart because the cache should be cleared for each retry to get appropriate results
to restart I'm using this command
os.system("shutdown /r")
after this command the code is ending abruptly and my question is after restart how to continue with further retries

Comment: So, your question is _not_ about restarting Windows (you seem to know how to do that), but about automatically starting your script after a restart. You will get better answers if you ask better questions.

Comment: You have to store within a temporary file the number of retries already done, and read them back at startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows tasks scheduler or create a windows service.

Here is an exemple with task scheduler : https://serverfault.com/questions/848968/task-scheduler-scheduled-task-at-startup-not-working